# How to get the fingerID (Touch) that is pressing a specific UI button. (Unity)

Tags: events, touch, unity-ui

I want to displace a button along with the screen position that is pressing on it.

However, having multiple touches at the same time results in wanky behaviour.

So I want to limit the button's movement to the touch that started it.

I'm aware of the [PointerEventData.pointerId](https://docs.unity3d.com/2018.3/Documentation/ScriptReference/EventSystems.PointerEventData-pointerId.html) but I couldn't figure out how to use it.

Answer (score 1):

Shortly after, I figured the problem was that I was not implementing the [IPointerDownHandler](https://docs.unity3d.com/2019.1/Documentation/ScriptReference/EventSystems.IPointerDownHandler.html) interface causing the [IPointerUpHandler](https://docs.unity3d.com/2019.1/Documentation/ScriptReference/EventSystems.IPointerUpHandler.html) to not work.

And this is the final script:

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.EventSystems;

public class VirtualJoystick : MonoBehaviour, IDragHandler, IPointerDownHandler, IPointerUpHandler
{
    [SerializeField] RectTransform joystickBG, joystickHandle;
    [HideInInspector] public Vector2 moveAxis;
    [Range(0, 2)] [SerializeField] float handleLimit;


    private void Awake()
    {
#if !(UNITY_ANDROID || UNITY_IOS) // || UNITY_EDITOR
        Destroy(gameObject);
#endif
    }


    public void OnPointerUp(PointerEventData eventData)
    {
        moveAxis = joystickHandle.anchoredPosition = Vector2.zero;
    }

    public void OnPointerDown(PointerEventData eventData)
    {
        moveAxis = ((Vector3)InputMaster.getPointerFromId(eventData.pointerId).position - joystickBG.position);
        joystickHandle.position = joystickBG.position + Vector3.ClampMagnitude(moveAxis, joystickBG.rect.width / 2 * handleLimit);
        moveAxis.Normalize();
    }

    public void OnDrag(PointerEventData eventData)
    {
        moveAxis = ((Vector3)InputMaster.getPointerFromId(eventData.pointerId).position - joystickBG.position);
        joystickHandle.position = joystickBG.position + Vector3.ClampMagnitude(moveAxis, joystickBG.rect.width / 2 * handleLimit);
        moveAxis.Normalize();
    }
}
```